# How to Redirect the page if the url has a different parameters or the route doesn't exist? in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

how to redirect the page if the route doesn't exist like

'sitename.me/asdasdas'

because when I'm trying to do this 
the NotFoundHttpException will show up.

please help me thanks

Comment: Please show the code you already tried with.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not have the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` for this purpose. Replace the `render()` and `unauthenticated()` function with the following.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) {
            // not found
            case 404:
                return redirect()->guest(your redirect url));
                break;

            // internal error
            case '500':
                return redirect()->guest(your redirect url));
                break;

            default:
                return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(your redirect url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to external domains, use the following:

```
return redirect()->away('http://sitename.me/asdasdas');
```

To redirect to an internal URI, use:

```
return redirect('admin/dashboard');
```

To redirect to an application route, use:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
```

For further reference, have a look at the [responses (redirects) documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#redirects).

Answer (score 0):

let me explain some details i have faced, Laravel throw common exception throw Handler.php file in app/Exceptions folder. In this file we have report function that throw common exception using render function.

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException){
        $this->render(null,$exception);
    } else {
        parent::report($exception);
    }
}
```

Above is an report function that throw any exception to render function specified below

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{        
    if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){
       // return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','Page Not Found',404);
    } else if ($exception instanceof ScopeHandler) {
        return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','Unauthorized',401);
    } else if ($exception instanceof \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException){
        return Helper::responseJson(null,'token','Unauthorized',401);
    } else if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
       // return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','Model Not Found',404);            
    } else if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException){
       // return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','Query Exception',400);            
    } else if ($exception instanceof \Swift_TransportException){
        return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','Mail send Exception',400);            
    }else if ($exception instanceof ConnectionFailedException){
        return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','Connection Exception',400);            
    }
     /* else if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException){
        return Helper::responseJson(null,'header','PHP config Exception',400);             
    } */

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

the above example of render function we used for throw exception using json format. we can redirect to specific page or we can do any functionality when these error thrown.